# I'm stuck on this algebra proof

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I've been stuck on this problem for some time now. It seems simple, but I have no idea how to proceed. I would genuinely appreciate it if anyone could help me break it down. Here's the problem:

Let $A:=\{m+\tfrac{5}{3}n:m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{Z}\},\ S:=\{\frac{k}{3}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}.$ Show that $A=S$.

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Bezout's identity.

Comment: Do you know what Linear Algebra is? If you do, why did you used that tag? If you don't, why did you used that tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general technique when asked to prove two sets are equal is to show that every element in one is in the other and vice versa.

In your example, consider any element $s \in S$. Then there is an integer $k$ such that $s=\frac{k}{3}$. Then $s=2k +\frac{5}{3}(-k)\in A$.

Now can you do the reverse process?